# How to collect data inside the rich text editor with $_POST?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

When I have the following:

```
  <?php

    $temp= file_get_contents('./inc/announcement.html');
    require_once(FACULTY180_CLASS_ROOT.'TinyMCEMaker.php');
    $richtext = new TinyMCEMaker('basic');
    $richtext->editor('Description', $temp);
    ?>
```

I will have a rich text editor. 
Also I know that if I have a form like

```
<?php
//  updating teh html file with new announcement

 if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit") 
   {
    $varMovie = $_POST['formMovie'];
    file_put_contents("./inc/announcement.html",$varMovie);     
   }
 ?>


 <form action="Home.php" method="post" id="announcement">

    <?php

    $temp= file_get_contents('./inc/announcement.html');
    require_once(FACULTY180_CLASS_ROOT.'TinyMCEMaker.php');
    $richtext = new TinyMCEMaker('basic');
    $richtext->editor('Description', $temp);
    ?>

     <input type="text" name="formMovie" id="Test" >

      <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit">

 </form>
```

when submit button is clicked, then can get  the value inside the input field with "forMovie" as name by $_POST.

So now insead of sending the value inside the input field, I want to send the value inside the rich text editor and then get it by $_POST.

I also know that I get the value inside the rich text editor by

```
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
```

but how can I send it? Becuase when I was sending the value inside the input field, I used the name of the input field in the $_POST ["NAME OF THE INPUT FIELD"]. but how does it work for my rich text editor?

Comment: `tinyMCE` should update the textarea you apply it to and the name of textarea is used. Have never used `TinyMCEMaker`, since is generally easy to intialize using javascript  ...looks like the name you wanted was `Description`